# Is there an enum helper that uses the Display annotation in Index and Details view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5.1

I have the following enum:

```
public enum QuoteStatus
{
    Open,
    [Display(Name = "On Hold")]
    Hold,
    Submitted,
    Cancelled,
    Won,
    Lost,
    Expired
}
```

When creating a Controller with Views using EF, the Create and Edit views use the `@Html.EnumDropDownListFor` helper. However, the Details and Index views use the `@Html.DisplayFor` helper.

I have searched around and have not found any recent posts on the subject. Is there a helper that I can use in the Details and Index views that would show **"On Hold"** in the view?

I would like to think using MVC 5.1 there would be such a helper, considering they have one for creating a drop down list, but I can't find it.